# How to input values in tinymce text editor for robotframework selenium2library in iframe?

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I was not able to input text using 'Input text' keyword, for texteditor body which is placed inside frame.. was able to do it with press key keyword.

```
Select Frame    editor_ifr          
sleep   5           
${1}    Get Text    //*[@id='tinymce']/p        
Press Key   //*[@id='tinymce']/p    abcde       
Comment Run Keyword And Ignore Error    Input Text  //*[@id='tinymce']/p    Test
Comment ${tst}  Run Keyword And Ignore Error    Execute Javascript  tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('Your text')
Comment Run Keyword And Ignore Error    Input Text  + "</p>'")  Test
${1}    Get Text    //*[@id='tinymce']/p
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. The first sentence says you are able to do it with the `press key` keyword. If so, what is your question?

Comment: Don't know tinymce, but Odoo has a WYSIWYG editor which is an iframe that simulates a text field. I can see the HTML code generated in the inspector as I type text in it. Is this the kind of field you have? Anyway, I've been able to enter text into it using this: Press Key    xpath=//div[@class='oe_form_field oe_form_field_html']//iframe    Hello World!

Answer (score 0):

I inputted text two ways, by javascript for phantomjs and selenium ***Input Text*** keyword.

```
# Select TinyMCE iframe for the instructions field.
Select Frame    id=tinymceIframe
sleep   5

# Input Text only works with browsers for tinymce. It's not working for phantomjs because the field in
# TinyMCE is a contenteditable element and not an input or textarea field.
Input Text    id=tinymce    This is works

# To side step the contenteditable field, for phantomjs, the content of the tinyMCE iframe body will be
# changed via JavaScript, if the browser is set to phantomjs
Run keyword if   '${BROWSER}' == 'phantomjs'  Execute Javascript   document.getElementById("tinymce").innerHTML='This is works';

# Ensure tinymce reflects this change in the text editor
Execute Javascript    function selectElementContents(el) {var range = document.createRange(); range.selectNodeContents(el); var sel = window.getSelection(); sel.removeAllRanges(); sel.addRange(range);} var el = document.getElementById("tinymce"); selectElementContents(el);

# Exit the TinyMCE iframe
Unselect Frame
```